# PHP: similar functionality of a jQuery $(this)?

Tags: php, if-statement, query-string, isset

I have a page where I can pass from one to three variables through the query string.

There are three cases:

- products.php?page=x
- products.php?gender=x&page=x
- products.php?gender=x&FILTER=x&page=x

The variables `page` and `gender` are always named like this, but the `FILTER` one can be three different things: `brand`, `category` and `subcategory`.

Because the `gender` variable is optional, I cannot use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get its name and value value because it's not always the second variable.

Based on the `FILTER` selected I do different things, each filter has a different functionality attached to it.

My question is: how can I know which of the three filters is selected after excluding `page` and `gender`, so basically if something like this is possible

```
if ( isset($_GET['brand']) || isset($_GET['category']) || isset($_GET['subcategory']) ) {

    // $selected = whichever variable is set, something like $(this) in jQuery

}
```

The alternative is to create an `if()` statement for each of the three cases, but if I will add more filters then I will have to add more `if()` statements.

Comment: `if (in_array($_GET['filter'], array('brand', 'category', 'subcategory'))`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but filter is just a placeholder for either one of the three variables. So the url could be products.php?brand=1 or it could be products.php?category=2. I need to know what the variable name is.

Comment: if filter is only one of three, why don't you use `&filter=category` and then php-side `switch($_GET['filter'])` ?

Comment: @C.Ovidiu Loop through `$_GET`?

Comment: How are you trying to pass in on the whatever function you have in there?

Comment: Surely you need to run different code based on the filter passed, so even i you could do what you suggested, you would need further ifs / switch case to process the correct code block. Might as well just use ifs

Comment: @birdspider I guess I will do just that, and to also pass the filter value I will do &filter=category-2, where the number matches the filer id. Alternatively &filter=category&filter-value=2

Comment: @C.Ovidiu yes, that was my imediate thought, but see me previous comment - will this really simplify your code at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could use if statements just like you said.

2) You could do something like

products.php?gender=x&filter=x+c&page=x

```
$filter = explode('+', $_GET['filter']));
$type = $filter[0] //x
$value = $filter[1] //c
```

Then you could use a switch for more readabilty

```
switch($type){
    case 'brand':
        //do stuff
        break;
    default:
        //do stuff
}
```